# How to choose any item from a list and add it to a different div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a block which has 12 items. Considering each item a `div`, I have one image and a caption for that in a `p` tag.

It is like goals that needs to be added to a different block on click of the items. Once clicked, the goals/items should get added to the other list with a close icon on the right end and the clicked item should become fader i.e opacity should reduce to 50%.

The user should be able to click any goals/items and depending upon that the items should get added to the other block like we add to cart in online shopping. How to do this using jQuery?

Comment: What did you tried so far? Post your code.

Comment: you have to post the code you have or tried. Now it is impossible to give you a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Well without seeing the code you have tried, here's a stab at my interpretation of your question:

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="clickme">Item</li>
    <li class="clickme">Item</li>
    <li class="clickme">Item</li>
</ul>

<div class="shoppingcart"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('clickme').click(function(){
    $('.shoppingcart').append(/*all the HTML you need for your item*/);
});
```

So this is the basic concept. Be more specific with your question and add some code you've attempted if you need a more detailed answer.